# How do I give form_with the proper route for nested namespaced models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app is growing large enough that, for organizational purposes, I want to start namespacing various items.  I now have FooBar::Act and FooBar::Show models, with each show having multiple acts.  I created a route namespaced with FooBar:

```
namespace :foo_bar do
  resources :shows do
    resources :acts, only: [:new, :create]
  end
  resources :acts, except: [:index, :new, :create]
end
```

Shows worked as expected.  Acts, however, are not.  I attempt to build a form using the following:

```
<%= form_with(model: @act, url: [@show, @act], local: true) do |form| %>
```

Instead of working, I get an error that foo_bar_show_foo_bar_acts doesn't exist, did I mean foo_bar_show_acts?

Based on some other stackoverflow answers, I tried using `def self.model_name` to remove the namespacing from the model name, but that didn't do a thing.

`Rails -v 5.1.4` & `Ruby -v 2.4.2p198`

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to use something more succinct, but I wound up defaulting back to using the path helper instead of letting it auto-generate the path.  I use auto-generated paths almost everywhere else to save typing / space / improve readability, not looking forward to where I'm gonna have to go from here.